# Do AJAX applications that use POST requests always fail in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, post

I have recently discovered that problems with intermittent failures for users running my application using Internet Explorer is due to a bug in Internet Explorer. The bug is in the HTTP stack, and should be affecting all applications using POST requests from IE. The result is a failure characterized by a request that seems to hang for about 5 minutes (depending on server type and configuration), then fail from the server end. The browser application will error out of the post request after the server gives up. I will explain the IE bug in detail below.

As far as I can tell this will happen with any application using XMLHttpRequest to send POST requests to the server, if the request is sent at the wrong moment. I have written a sample program that attempts to send the POSTS at just those times. It attempts to send continuous POSTs to the server at the precise moment the server closes the connections. The interval is derived from the Keep-Alive header sent by the server.

I am finding that when running from IE to a server with a bit of latency (i.e. not on the same LAN), the problem occurs after only a few POSTs. When it happens, IE locks up so hard that it has to be force closed. The ticking clock is an indication that the browser is still responding.

You can try it by browsing to: http://pubdev.hitech.com/test.post.php. **Please take care that you don't have any important unsaved information in any IE session when you run it, because I am finding that it will crash IE.**

The full source can be retrieved at: http://pubdev.hitech.com/test.post.php.txt. You can run it on any server that has php and is configured for persistent connections.

My questions are:

1. What are other people's experiences with this issue?
2. Is there a known strategy for working around this problem (other than "use another browser")?
3. Does Microsoft have better information about this issue than the article I found (see below)?

The problem is that web browsers and servers by default use persistent connections as described in RFC 2616 section 8.1 (see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). This is very important for performance--especially for AJAX applications--and should not be disabled. There is however a small timing hole where the browser may start to send a POST on a previously used connection at the same time the server decides the connection is idle and decides to close it. The result is that the browser's HTTP stack will get a socket error because it is using a closed socket. RFC 2616 section 8.1.4 anticipates this situation, and states, "...clients, servers, and proxies MUST be able to recover from asynchronous close events. Client software SHOULD reopen the transport connection and retransmit the aborted sequence of requests without user interaction..."

Internet Explorer *does* resend the POST when this happens, but when it does it mangles the request. It sends the POST headers, including the Content-Length of the data as posted, but it does not send the data. This is an improper request, and the server will wait an unspecified amount of time for the promised data before failing the request with an error. I have been able to demonstrate this failure 100% of the time using a C program that simulates an HTTP server, which closes the socket of an incoming POST request without sending a response.

Microsoft seems to acknowledge this failure in  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895954. They say that it affects IE versions 6 through 9. That provide a hotfix for this problem, that has shipped with all versions of IE since IE 7. The hotfix does not seem satisfactory for the following reasons:

1. It is not enabled unless you use regedit to add a key called FEATURE_SKIP_POST_RETRY_ON_INTERNETWRITEFILE_KB895954 to the registry. This is not something I would expect my users to have to do.
2. The hotfix does not actually fix the broken POST. Instead, if the socket gets closed as anticipated by the RFC, it simply errors out immediately without trying to resent the POST. The application still fails--it just fails sooner.

The following example is a self contained php program that demonstrates the bug. It attempts to send continuous POSTs to the server at the precise moment the server closes the connections. The interval is derived from the Keep-Alive header sent by the server.

Comment: Did you ever discover a way around this?  I am experiencing the same issue using jQuery ajax post operations.

Comment: @tony-abo I am running into similar issue. Curious to know if there is a fix for this? Also why does not it happen for GET request? Is it because the GET does not have any BODY and hence on network failure the resend is successful?

Answer (score 6):

We've encountered this problem with IE on a regular basis.  There is no good solution.  The only solution that is guaranteed to solve the problem is to ensure that the web server keepalive timeout is higher than the browser keepalive timeout (by default with IE this is 60s).  Any situation where the web server is set to a lower value can result in IE attempting to reuse the connection and sending a request that gets rejected with a TCP RST because the socket has been closed.  If the web server keepalive timeout value is higher than IE's keepalive timeout then IE's reuse of the connections ensure that the socket won't be closed.  With high latency connections you'll have to consider the latency time as the time spent in-transit could be an issue.

Keep in mind however, that increasing the keepalive on the server means that an idle connection is using server sockets for that much longer.  So you may need to size the server to handle a large number of inactive idle connections.  This can be a problem as it may result in a burst of load to the server that the server isn't able to handle.

Another thing to keep in mind.  You note that the RFC section 8.1.4 states :"...clients, servers, and proxies MUST be able to recover from asynchronous close events. Client software SHOULD reopen the transport connection and retransmit the aborted sequence of requests without user interaction..."

You forgot a very important part.  Here's the full text:
   Client software SHOULD reopen the
   transport connection and retransmit the aborted sequence of requests
   without user interaction so long as the request sequence is
   idempotent (see section 9.1.2). Non-idempotent methods or sequences
   MUST NOT be automatically retried, although user agents MAY offer a
   human operator the choice of retrying the request(s). Confirmation by
   user-agent software with semantic understanding of the application
   MAY substitute for user confirmation. The automatic retry SHOULD NOT
   be repeated if the second sequence of requests fails

An HTTP POST is non-idempotent as defined by 9.1.2.  Thus the behavior of the registry hack is actually technically correct per the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

No, generally POST works in IE. It may be an issue, what you are saying, 
but it isn't such a major issue to deserve this huge a post.

And when you issue POST ajax request, to make sure every browser inconsistency is covered, just use jquery.

One more thing:
Noone sane will tell you to "use another browser" because IE is widely used and needs to be taken care of (well, except IE6 and for some, maybe even some newer versions)

So, POST **has** to work in IE, but to make yourself covered for unexpected buggy behavior, use jquery and you can sleep well.

Comment: This is indeed happening. When I say intermittent, I mean anywhere from 1% to 10% of the POSTs depending on the server. How can you say that is not a major issue? It doesn't matter which javascript library you use because the problem is in the HTTP stack. You will get an error back from the POST. What do you do then?

Answer (score 0):

I have never encountered this issue. And our clients mostly runs IE6.

I suspect you've configured your keep-alive timer too long. Most people configure it to be under 1 second because persistent connections are only meant to speed up page loading not service Ajax calls.

If you have keep-alive configured too long you'll face much more severe problems than IE crashing - your server will run out file descriptors to open sockets!*

* note: *Incidentally, opening and not closing connections to HTTP servers is a well known DOS attack that tries to force the server to reach its max open socket limit. Which is why most server admins also configure connection timeouts to avoid having sockets open for too long.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Some thoughts:

Comment: The keep-alive default changed from 15 seconds in Apache 2.0 to 5 seconds in Apache 2.2. I have not explicitly changed them on servers running my application.

It seems to me that this problem would happen with any keep alive timeout setting, so long as the next request occurs at the moment the connection is being closed. The only way to be sure it never happens would be to disable persistent connections altogether.

Comment: How frequently are AJAX POSTS sent in your application? Even if it is infrequent, is it possible that your users are experiencing a once in a blue moon problem where the application seems to freeze up and they have to start over?

My application is extremely dynamic and can send lots of AJAX requests in response to user interaction. Without connection pooling, it would be opening and closing connections at an alarming rate.

Comment: Have you tried the example? I would be interested in knowing whether it hangs up your IE 6.

Thanks again.

Comment: I don't remember the stats exactly but I think the average rate of ajax request was something like once every 10 seconds or so. I haven't tested your code but just think about this: Facebook uses lots of Ajax. And look at their headers, they've enabled keep-alive. Has facebook ever crashed the way you described? With around a billion users someone must have noticed it if it really is a big problem.

Comment: Now that's interesting about Facebook. Looking at some traces, it sends a "Connection: keep-alive", but no "Keep-Alive" header. It appears that the server never closes the connections. It looks like the browser closes some of them (with RST instead of FIN). Maybe that's my answer. Perhaps I can set "KeepAlive On" and "KeepAliveTimeout 0".

Comment: FYI, KeepAliveTimeout 0 does not work. It causes Apache to send Connection: close headers on all responses.